# How to find original URL behind the translate.goog link?

Tags: google-translate

[A] https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/
[B] https://translate.google.com/website?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/
[C] https://hz2cpxsvz5qtrxmqge7znoupci--opensource-faculty.translate.goog/docs/components/navbar/

[A] is original link, [B] is used to create a google translate link, [C] is google translate link, [B] is redirected to [C].

Question:
I have got only the link [C] as text. I would like to get original link from [C]. How can I get the original link [A] from google translate link [C]? Maybe there is an API get original link.

What I found is if we send HTTP request to [C] it returns response and it has an iframe in  tag. In iframe's src attribute there is an original url as query parameter. I need to parse the response and find the [A] from it. This solution is a  fallback solution if I don't find better one. I'm trying to find a better solution.

Comment: The question seems to be outdated. Google is now generating simpler URLs: https://dash--bootstrap--components-opensource-faculty-ai.translate.goog/

Comment: @LatinSuD That is not always true. Phishing adversaries are still generating these mangled URLs to mask phishing attack URLs. So, there is still a way to generate the mangled URLs.

Answer (score 2):

In the [C] response there is `<base href="https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/">` which contains the original URL.